# javac -cp parameter's error "javac: file not found:"

Tags: java, compilation, classpath, javac

My question is about one of the basic java command "javac". I have a ".java" file  on my desktop.I have installed JDK 7 and added path variable to the environment variables. Here is the screenshot of the "environment variables". 
http://s13.postimage.org/n0oc89gp3/Untitled.png

When I'm working in C:\Users\JOXWH\Desktop there is no problem.Such as; If I try this code in here `javac JavaApplication2.java`. I'm having .class file on my desktop. But if I try to use javac from another directory with -cp parameter (like `javac -cp C:\Users\JOXWH\Desktop JavaApplication2.java`) I'm taking an error like this: http://postimage.org/image/4aps9ntlr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need of -cp `javac C:\Users\JOXWH\Desktop JavaApplication2.java`

will work

Comment: yes that code can work "javac  C:\Users\JOXWH\Desktop\JavaApplication2.java" .But what is the problem with -cp?

Comment: you should specify class path after -cp, for eg: javac -cp . JavaApplication.java will work as it sets current directory as classpath. (dot means current dir)

Comment: I think you're wrong there.it is possible to use it with javac. here is javac options :http://s9.postimage.org/y1uvinqu7/Untitled.png

Comment: you can use -cp with javac but you should mention a path after that

Comment: So how can ı edit this code, I think it is including path after -cp parameter :"javac -cp C:\Users\JOXWH\Desktop JavaApplication2.java"

Comment: suppose your MainApplicaton2.java requires a external class  to compile, in such cases you can use -cp option otherwise no need to use. javac -cp classes-dir C:\Users\JOXWH\Desktop JavaApplication2.java, then javac will lookup classes-dir to look for dependencies

Answer (score 0):

`-cp` tells the compiler where to look for *other* classes that the `.java` file(s) you are compiling depend on, not where to look for the java source files themselves. You need to give the appropriate paths to the java files in full.

In all but the most trivial cases the source file locations and the required class locations will be different, e.g.

```
javac -cp classes;lib\* -d classes src\com\example\MyClass.java
```

would take a `.java` file from under `src` which depends on classes under `classes` and on classes in jar files under `lib`, compile it, and put the resulting class file under `classes` in a directory matching the class's package name.